# PHPMailer not sending any email

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer library to send email but it is not sending any email,I tried since morning but still I am unable to send any email it is showing error this page is not working
phpmailer.php,smtp and test.php in same directory help me to solve this issue.
Code in test.php

```
<?php

    // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
    // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    
    
    //require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
     include("PHPMailer.php"); 
     include("SMTP.php"); 
     include("Exception.php"); 
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = 'abc@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'xxxxx';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('receiver@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    
        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
    
        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
?>
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error that could mean ANYTHING related to the server. You need to look at your error log.

Comment: I think your problem is you are trying to `use` `PHPMailer` before it's even `include`ded.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I checked  in cpanel error log but no issue mentioned

Comment: Well, I can't really help you outside of my second comment. I don't know anything about your environment and I can't pick out anything else wrong in your code from a quick glance. I'm betting your error happens before your `try` block though.

Comment: could u please send any working example,I followed so many links  but didn't work

Comment: Just try to switch all of the `include` statements to be above the `use` statements.

Comment: as per your suggestion I did but didn't work

Comment: Then I will need an actual error code from your server. I can't do anything based on a 500 error.

Comment: In phpmailer I didn't find autoload.php but in so many websites  i.e blog they are asking to include, but in github directory also no autoload.php file present

Comment: I have a project which uses phpmailer, I only include `class.smtp.php` and `class.phpmailer.php`. I don't use `use` at all.

Comment: Not possible to do, sorry.

Comment: Turn on the error reporting, you will get the error message. And update your answer here. It could help you and us better understand the problem.

Comment: `Use` *should be* before `include`. `Use` doesn't require that the class actually exists or is loaded, it simply defines a mapping into your local namespace. You don't necessarily need to use `use` at all as you can always use FQCNs instead, but it makes the code easier to read. @GrumpyCrouton – those class names are many years out of date, and were from an old version of PHPMailer that did not use a namespace.

Comment: I recommend reading [the PHPMailer readme](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which tells you how to get an `autoload.php` file for your project (use composer, which you should learn to use before you do *anything* else).

Comment: @Synchro It was my best guess because I was assuming the error happened before the `try` block. Was the only thing I could think of. I'll look into updating my phpmailer package on my project, thanks.

Comment: Also don't use `include` for things that are critical. You want to create a PHPMailer instance which *absolutely requires that you have PHPMailer loaded*, but if you use `include` to load the class files you won't find out if they failed until you try to create a class instance later on. If things are going to fail, you want them to fail as early as possible as it makes the problem much easier to track down, so use `require`. OTOH, use composer, as it takes care of all of this loading business for you.

Comment: As always, whatever other issues you run into, [read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide first](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) as it contains pretty much everything you're likely to have trouble with, including all the questions you have raised here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix! `$mail->Host` is a web request not a socket and 465 is the wrong port! Try

```php
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->Port = 587;
```

example: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: it is showing error SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

Comment: do you have a 2fa active?

Comment: what is that 2fa

Comment: I followed your posted link but no autoload.php file present

Comment: replace require autoload with 
`
include("PHPMailer.php"); 
include("SMTP.php"); 
include("Exception.php"); `

Comment: The `Host` property *can* use the format in the OP's code; it's a kind of shortcut for setting the `SMTPSecure` property as well. `ssl` encryption mode *does* require `Port = 465`, and it will not work on port 587. The example you linked to uses `tls` encryption mode, which *will* work on port 587.

Comment: I changed that and I got an authentication problem because I have 2fa active but the request was executed successfully. I can't help further without digging deeper